# ssh resolves -p 1234 hostname=“localhost” but does not resolve hostname=“localhost:1234”

Tags: ssh

I upgraded to Fedora 20 a few weeks back. I had very few issues in the upgrade process and the system is stable. One lingering issue I have is described below.

I have one computer on my LAN with a reverse port forward set up back to the recently updated fedora 20 machine. I can verify the reverse forward works because the following is successful from the fedora 20 computer:

```
$ ssh -p 1234 xxxxx@localhost 
xxxxxx@localhost's password: 
Last login: Mon Dec  1 14:08:22 2014 from localhost.localdomain
```

However if I specify the port number after localhost I get a “could not resolve” error as shown below:

```
$ ssh -v xxxxx@localhost:1234
OpenSSH_6.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 51: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname localhost:1234: Name or service not known
```

So in the first situation it sees hostname=localhost and resolves that to an IP address. In the second situation it sees hostname=”localhost:1234:”  ...

The contents of /etc/host is :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain localhost
::1     localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

Right now I'm trying to determine if this is a resolving thing or something else. a "dig localhost" doesn't return an answer section so that suggest it is. At the same time localhost:port#  works in a browser. I don't know how localhost is resolved from /etc/hosts, I assume NetworkManager does this? I'm not running any sort of internal DNS server on my LAN.

I'm happy to provide additional information if requested & thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ssh -v xxxxx@localhost:1234
ssh: Could not resolve hostname localhost:1234: Name or service not known
```

"user@host:port" or "host:port" simply aren't valid syntax for specifying a destination on the ssh command line. ssh treats everything after the "@" as a hostname. It doesn't treat part of that field as a port number, and it's not documented to do so.

The specific error indicates that ssh is trying to look up the IP address for a nonexistent host named "localhost:1234" and failing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the -p option to specify a port with SSH, not the hostname:port format.

```
ssh -v xxxxx@localhost -p 1234
```